# Conflict on solution with two services

Tags: servicestack

I've been trying to set up a solution with the following scenario:

1. Client app X calls Service A
2. Service A calls Class Library Y
3. Class Library Y calls Service B

So the projects reference each other in this way:

- Client app X -> references Service A
- Service A -> references Class Library Y
- Class Library Y -> References Service B

I have configured the project to start debug all projects (except class library) and the services are running under IIS Express on different ports.

When I use SocialBootstrapApi project as template for the services and I start debugging, Service A starts fine but I get a compilation error on Service B:

```
CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'ServiceStack.Mvc.Bundler.ToJsBool(bool)' and 'ServiceStack.Mvc.Bundler.ToJsBool(bool)'
```

on line

```
App.models.login.set({ isAuthenticated: @session.IsAuthenticated.ToJsBool() });
```

I also tested using an empty ASP.NET project + ServiceStack.Host.AspNet as template, again Service A runs but I get a

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: AppHostBase.Instance has already been set
```

on line

```
new AppHost().Init();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to launch a host within other working host. I would suggest you to reorder and decouple the dependencies.

You might do this by:

- Library Y exposes an interface /contract with its own needs. No direct reference to any service is hard-coded.
- Service B implement that interface (or library B do it).
- Then Service A or AppX are the unique hosts that configure all services, and you hook all parts with IoC container.

I could make a better proposal if more concrete description of services, etc. are given. Servicestack let you decouple inter-services calls through the IoC container and also through IMessageService